# Using double quotes vs single quotes when passing string as a parameter to function

Tags: php, mysql, quotes

i have a very strange problem, well not really a problem because i've fixed it but still,
when i'm trying to connect to mysql db with:

```
mysql_connect("server", "user", "pass") or die(mysql_error());
```

im getting:

> Access denied for user 'user'@'server' (using password: YES)

but when i change the quotes around the password to single quotes:

```
mysql_connect("server", "user", 'pass') or die(mysql_error());
```

it works just fine.
i dont have this problem in another server i've got.
so maybe it's something in the mysql settings or in the php.ini?

thanks.

Comment: Your password has a `$` in it, doesn't it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must have a `$` in your password.

That will cause php to interpolate a variable in the string.

You might also have an escape sequence, e.g., `\t` in your password which will cause similar problems.

Check out the manual for more info:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing

Answer (score 2):

Does your password contain any special characters like `$`? In double quotes PHP will try to interpret variables. Thus `"My$Password"` would yield in PHP looking for a variable called `$Password`, which isn't there. So the resulting password string will be simply `My`. (If you have enabled showing `E_NOTICE` errors you should get one.)

Furthermore special character sequences like `\n` are interpreted within double quotes.